# SQL password embedded in excel

Tags: sql-server, excel

I'm working on a workbook in excel with multiple worksheets many of which have links to ODBC SQL server. To gain password access each have UID=xxxxxx;PWD=xxxxxx, embedded in them to gain access to the SQL Server. What I am trying to do is have each user access SQL with their own password so I don't want to use the save password option.

Also due to the large number of worksheets I would like to is set up the workbook so that rather than the user input their password multiple times I would like to have the workbook set up so the user will only need to input their password once.

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Comment: Could use Active Directory authentication? That way you set up the login on SQL Server to allow particular Windows domain users access, and they'll just go straight in without a password. That way you don't have to store passwords in a spreadsheet, which is obviously dangerous.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me Matt. I'll give that a try and see if it works.